# Change Application Locale Runtime

Tags: java, android

I want to update app locale on language selection.

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(LocaleHelper.onAttach(context));
}
```

Fragment in main activity to select language. On selection I have wrote below code:

```
private View.OnClickListener updateLanguage() {
    return (View v) -> {
        String code = v.getTag() != null ? v.getTag().toString() : getString(R.string.en_code);

        LocaleHelper.setLocale(getContext(), code);
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_languageFragment_to_instructionFragment);
    };
}
```

On selection of language I am updating locale using below code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
Locale.setDefault(locale);

Resources resources = context.getResources();
Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
config.setLocale(locale);

return context.createConfigurationContext(config);
```

After selection redirects to next screen, but language is not getting updated. It is updated if I re-launch app.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code works fine with me

```
       Resources resources = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17){ config.locale = new Locale(localecode.toLowerCase()); }
        else { config.setLocale(new Locale(localecode.toLowerCase())); }
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, dm);
```